# Generating a DataFrame with column names for correlation values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a loop that iterates over columns calculating correlation:

`For column in df Print (ds[column].corr(ds[”something”])`

I need to get an output as df with columns names next to my output

I.e:
Column 1: 0.17
Column2: 0.333
Column 3: 0.004

I tried to create an empty df and failed, it prints just as []

Important: result I get is a list. It is a must to append this list to columns in list df (df is a list, and ds is data frame)

Comment: What about using the builting function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin method [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to get a dataframe output

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(.2, .3), (.0, .6), (.6, .0), (.2, .1)],
                  columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
df.corr()
# returns
#   dogs    cats
# dogs  1.000000    -0.851064
# cats  -0.851064   1.000000
```

Mis-read your question, and missed the bit where you are only looking for the correlation against one of the columns:

Faster method:

```py
ds[ [col for col in df if col != 'something']].corrwith(ds['something'])
```

Comment: No, it does not solve anything. Correlations are the result of iteration over columns in existing df with like 70 columns

Comment: @MOP edited my answer, I had missed the part where you only want the corrlations against one of the columns, proposing a much faster answer now

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately, it does not work, and actually there is DF and DS - different frames

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working? Is it raising an error or not giving the wanted output?

Comment: Have edited the code to use `ds` data instead of `df`